# How to round trip an object with relation using asp .net web api, entity framework and json (code first)?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, code-first

Using a .NET client app, I am trying to post an object A that includes a collection of objects B via asp .net web api JSON, have that create a LocalDB database, and store the data. Then fetch object A again.

The app includes 3 projects. A asp .net mvc 4 web api project, a .Net console app and a .Net class library. Both the asp .net app and console app reference the class library, which includes the class definitions for objects A and B.

Class library:

```
public class Actor
{
    public Actor()
    {
        this.Movies = new HashSet<Movie>();
    }

    public int ActorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        this.Actors = new HashSet<Actor>();
    }

    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

Console App:

```
Movie movie = new Movie()
{
    Name = "Dr. No"
};

Actor actor = new Actor()
{
    Name = "Sean Connery"
};

movie.Actors.Add(actor);

using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:3654");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<Movie>("api/movies", movie).Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    response = client.GetAsync("api/movies/1").Result;
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    Movie newMovie = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Movie>().Result;
}
```

asp .net mvc DbContext:

```
public class MediaContext : DbContext
{
    public MediaContext()
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

**Problem #1:** It seems JSON doesn't like the circular reference, however if I don't add the collection to both objects, EF5 does not create a MoviesActors table to hold the reference.

**Problem #2:** Even if I add the reference in the controller, when I return that object, it doesn't return it with the Actors. E.g. I expected something like

```
Movie
{
   MovieID = "1",
   Name = "???",
   Actors[] = { 1 }
}
```

But instead, Actors is just null.

**Update**: Here is the self-referencing exception:

ExceptionMessage=Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Movie_157D88BDC89E46A7CE4875C2970C7BBFB893972095EFA0745C2261AACC007969'. Path '[0].Actors[0].Movies'.

I managed to work around this exception using the method at [How did I solve the Json serializing circular reference error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754375/how-did-i-solve-the-json-serializing-circular-reference-error) and just disabling the proxy. That solves problem #1. However when I get the Movies, they still come back with no Actors, even using Include("Actors"). I can see the reference has been created correctly in the intermediate table in the LocalDb.

**Update 2**

FINALLY figured this out, answer below.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Where is a circular reference? In your example the `actor.Movies` collection is empty, only `movie.Actors` is filled. I don't see entities refering to each other. And what does it mean that "JSON doesn't *like* the circular reference"? Do you get an exception somewhere? And what is exactly the code for "when I return that object"? You have disabled lazy loading, so you can't rely on that. Do you use eager loading with `Include`?

Comment: So the Movies controller is stock standard VS generated. I tried with and without Include eager loading. E.g. return db.Movies.Include("Actors").AsEnumerable();. On the PostAsJsonAsync I had a BP on the return response, and the response was 201. However I then got an exception at response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); with a 500 error. Using Fiddler I looked at the actual response, and it had a circular reference exception. I've done about 10 tutorial walk throughs, and hours of searching and can't seem to figure out how to even get this simple scenario to work.

Comment: Also, I'd be completely happy to remove the public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; } from the Actor class, however in doing that, EF wasn't generating the intermediate table in the LocalDb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much searching I was finally able to resolve my issue. Originally I tried adding a [ScriptIgnore] tag to the Movies set, however I was using EF5 final which changed the default serializer to JSON .NET. I finally found that [ScriptIgnore] didn't work and I had to set [JsonIgnore] like this:

```
public class Actor
{
    public int ActorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

Doing that combined with the .Include("Actors") eager loading in the Get method finally solved my issue.

In summary I needed to:

1. Have the virtual ICollection references on both objects to create the intermediate table.
2. Add [JsonIgnore] to the Movies collection reference to solve the circular reference.
3. Turn off the proxy to solve my 500 error.
4. Eager load the Actors in the GetMovies/GetMovie method using .Include("Actors")

Additionally I found for subsequent PUTs of the Movie object, where the Actors collection had changed, I had to manually change the RelationShip state on each child Actor to either Added/Deleted to make sure the related collection was updated.

Comment: worked a treat, quick note for anyone scanning the answer and throwing it in without reading fully (like me), you need the Json.NET package and then add a using for "using Newtonsoft.Json;"

Answer (score 1):

About your comment:

> Also, I'd be completely happy to remove the `public virtual
>   ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }` from the Actor class, however
>   in doing that, EF wasn't generating the intermediate table in the
>   LocalDb.

If you remove one of the collections EF assumes by convention that your relationship is a one-to-many relationship (which doesn't have an intermediate table, but only a foreign key in one of the tables) in contrast to the model with two collections where EF creates a many-to-many relationship (that has an intermediate table).

However, you can override this convention using Fluent API and tell EF explicitly that the remaining collection belongs to a many-to-many relationship instead of a one-to-many. Having this model...

```
public class Actor
{
    //...
    public int ActorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    //...
    public int MovieID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

...you can define a many-to-many relationship this way:

```
public class MediaContext : DbContext
{
    //...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Movie>()
            .HasMany(m => m.Actors)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(a =>
            {
                a.MapLeftKey("MovieID");
                a.MapRightKey("ActorID");
                a.ToTable("MovieActors"); // intermediate table
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, still had a similar issue with the circular reference. As I understand, defining the relationship using the Fluent API is really designed for the scenario where you already have a database set up. In this case, I wanted to do it completely code-first and have the db generated for me.

Comment: @Luke: It's not quite correct. Fluent API is part of Code-First, not Database-First. It just offers some more and advanced features over data annotations, but the purpose - mapping a model to a DB schema (and generate the DB) - is the same.